# telegram not compile with ndk 18

Tags: android, android-ndk

When i try compile telegram with android studio 3.2, i get an error:
    Android NDK: Invalid NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION value: 4.9. GCC is no longer supported.
I know, what from version of android ndk 18 and more gcc is no longer supported, but how i can fix this error in telegram, or it's better wait new version of telegram on github? When i tryed delete string in application.nk file,connected with version of toolch, i got another errors, connected with cpp files. Help me please compile telegram,without downgrading ndk. Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: I see similar issues with NDK18. Try reverting back your NDK to 15 or 16.

Comment: _"i got another errors, connected with cpp files"_ It's impossible to say what the problem might be until you've posted the exact errors, and the code/makefiles that causes the errors.

Comment: In my opinion,it not good idea use old versions of ndk. When i delete string

Comment: NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9 I download telegram from github https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram. Thanks very mucheverybody for any help.

Comment: I can't add errors,because it's limitation of length of my message in comments.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using old versions of ndk for your purposes. Try reverting to 14-16 as suggested earlier.

Answer (score 3):

The issues are pretty straightforward to fix: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/pull/1483

Comment: I try compile telegram with your changes,but i still get an errors: > GNUMAKE: Expected exactly one source file in compile step: com.android.build.gradle.external.gnumake.CommandClassifier$NativeCompilerBuildTool@5d344e2f
  but received: 
  '-DVERSION=1.3.1'
  C:/Users/ksash/Desktop/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./exoplayer/libFLAC/bitmath.c
  in command:
  -MMD
  -MP
  -MF
  -target
  armv7-none-linux-androideabi16
  -ffunction-sections
  -fdata-sections
  -funwind-tables
  -no-canonical-prefixes
  -g
  -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument
  -gcc-toolchain

Comment: If you google the error you'll find https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/561. Opened https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/pull/1485

Answer (score 0):

So,

```
Remove the NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION line (or set it to clang) to build with clang.
```

is the fix.