# NDK error when build Telegram source in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, telegram, ndk-build

I download the telegram source from github with Git Bash:

> git clone git@github.com:DrKLO/Telegram.git
>
> git submodule update --init --recursive

- `NDK`, `CMK`, `LLDB` installed.

But shows a ndkBuild error :

> Cause: executing external native build for ndkBuild
>   D:\Teleg\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk

- no spaces between all directory names

cmd ndk-build :

[image]

Comment: so tried `android-16` min version as your error says?

Comment: I don't know what that error means ! and how i can fix all off kind of error ?

Comment: did you see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErfaB.jpg)? now you are using `android-14` which is **not** supported

Comment: yes dude ! what to do ? How to fix that error ?

Comment: find `14` in your project configuration files?

Comment: Where is the configuration files ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [telegram not compile with ndk 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670082/telegram-not-compile-with-ndk-18)

Comment: I tried ndk 17 and 15 but still got that errors